# When a variable switches from 1 to 2, delete some data from the other variables and average what's left?

Tags: r

I am analysing some data and need help.

Basically, I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
date <- seq(as.Date("2017-04-01"),as.Date("2017-05-09"),length.out=40)
switch <- c(rep(1:2,each=10),rep(1:2,each=10))
O2 <- runif(40,min=21.02,max=21.06)
CO2 <- runif(40,min=0.076,max=0.080)
test.data <- data.frame(date,switch,O2,CO2)
```

As can be seen, there's a switch column that switches between 1 and 2 every 10 data points. I want to write a code that does: when the "switch" column changes its value (from 1 to 2, or 2 to 1), delete the first 5 rows of data after the switch (i.e. leaving the 5 last data points for all the 4 variables), average the rest of the data points for O2 and CO2, and put them in 2 new columns (avg.O2 and avg.CO2) before the next switch. Then repeat this process until the end.

It's quite easy to do manually on paper or excel, but my real dataset would comprise thousands of data points and I would like to use R to do it automatically for me. So anyone has any ideas that could help me?

Comment: What is with the first 5 rows of the dataframe? Should they deleted? Is the change in the switch always after 10 repeated values?

Comment: Use `set.seed` to make your example reproducible and show what you would like your desired output to be for the given example. It is not entirely clear from the text.

Comment: Can we assume the switch is reliable? It happens every time after every 10 points?

Comment: @jogo yes the switch is always after 10 points, as it's how my machine is set up to get data from 2 different sources (hence the 1 and 2). The first 5 rows of each switch is considered "not reliable", because after each switch, it took a while for the machine to stabilise and record accurate data. The number "5" was determined using Allan Variance analysis techniques (which I don't think needs to be detailed here).

Comment: @LukášHejtmánek yes, please see my comment above

Comment: When you say "average the rest of the data points for O2 and CO2, and put them in 2 new columns" are you saying for the remaining 5 rows per switch, place an additional column that repeats the same average 5 times?

Comment: @lmo I don't get what you're saying. The code I provided can be run by anyone to generate a test dataset, so it's already reproducible (noted that I use the random generator because the exact numbers aren't what I'm looking for since the numbers are from my machine - which are several thousands of data points). My desired output is, I think, quite clearly stated: I would like R to do what I want, then add the calculated values to 2 new columns to the data frame.

Comment: @EvanFriedland either that, or place the average value at the start (or end) of the those 5 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find my edits which should work for both regular and irregular

```
date <- seq(as.Date("2017-04-01"),as.Date("2017-05-09"),length.out=40)
switch <- c(rep(1:2,each=10),rep(1:2,each=10))
O2 <- runif(40,min=21.02,max=21.06)
CO2 <- runif(40,min=0.076,max=0.080)
test.data <- data.frame(date,switch,O2,CO2)

    CleanMachineData <- function(Data, SwitchData, UnreliableRows = 5){
  # First, we can properly turn your switch column into a grouping column (1,2,1,2)->(1,2,3,4)
  grouplength <- rle(Data[,"switch"])$lengths
  # mapply lets us input vector arguments into typically one/first-element only argument functions. 
  # In this case we create a sequence of lengths (output is a list/vector)
  grouping <- mapply(seq, grouplength)
  # Here we want it to become a single vector representing groups
  groups <- mapply(rep, 1:length(grouplength), each = grouplength)
  # if frequency was irregular, it will be a list, if regular it will be a matrix
  # convert either into a vector by doing as follows:
  if(class(grouping) == "list"){
    groups <- unlist(groups)
  } else {
    groups <- as.vector(groups)
  }
  Data$group <- groups
  #
  # vector of the first row of each new switch (except the starting 0)
  switchRow <- c(0,which(abs(diff(SwitchData)) == 1))+1
  # I use "as.vector" to turn the matrix output of mapply into a sequence of numbers.
  # "ToRemove" will have all the row numbers to get rid of from your original data, except for what happens before (in this case) row 10
  ToRemove <- c(1:UnreliableRows, as.vector(mapply(seq, switchRow, switchRow+(UnreliableRows)-1)))
  # I concatenate the missing beginning (1,2,3,4,5) and theToRemove them with c() and then remove them from n with "-"
  Keep <- seq(nrow(Data))[-c(1:UnreliableRows,ToRemove)]
  # Create the new data, (in case you don't know: data[<ROW>,<COLUMN>])
  newdat <- Data[-ToRemove,]
  # print the results
  newdat
}
dat <- CleanMachineData(test.data, test.data$switch, 5)
dat
date switch       O2        CO2 group
6  2017-04-05      1 21.03922 0.07648886     1
7  2017-04-06      1 21.04071 0.07747368     1
8  2017-04-07      1 21.05742 0.07946615     1
9  2017-04-08      1 21.04673 0.07782362     1
10 2017-04-09      1 21.04966 0.07936446     1
16 2017-04-15      2 21.02526 0.07833825     2
17 2017-04-16      2 21.04511 0.07747774     2
18 2017-04-17      2 21.03165 0.07662803     2
19 2017-04-18      2 21.03252 0.07960098     2
20 2017-04-19      2 21.04032 0.07892145     2
26 2017-04-25      1 21.03691 0.07691438     3
27 2017-04-26      1 21.05846 0.07857017     3
28 2017-04-27      1 21.04128 0.07891908     3
29 2017-04-28      1 21.03837 0.07817021     3
30 2017-04-29      1 21.02334 0.07917546     3
36 2017-05-05      2 21.02890 0.07723042     4
37 2017-05-06      2 21.04606 0.07979641     4
38 2017-05-07      2 21.03822 0.07985775     4
39 2017-05-08      2 21.04136 0.07781525     4
40 2017-05-09      2 21.05375 0.07941123     4

aggregate(cbind(O2,CO2) ~ group, dat, mean)
group       O2        CO2
1     1 21.04675 0.07812336
2     2 21.03497 0.07819329
3     3 21.03967 0.07834986
4     4 21.04166 0.07882221

# crazier, irregular switching
test.data2 <- test.data
test.data2$switch <- unlist(mapply(rep, 1:2, times = 1, each = c(10,8,10,5,3,10)))[1:20]
dat2 <- CleanMachineData(test.data2, test.data2$switch, 5)
dat2
date switch       O2        CO2 group
6  2017-04-05      1 21.03922 0.07648886     1
7  2017-04-06      1 21.04071 0.07747368     1
8  2017-04-07      1 21.05742 0.07946615     1
9  2017-04-08      1 21.04673 0.07782362     1
10 2017-04-09      1 21.04966 0.07936446     1
16 2017-04-15      2 21.02526 0.07833825     2
17 2017-04-16      2 21.04511 0.07747774     2
18 2017-04-17      2 21.03165 0.07662803     2
24 2017-04-23      1 21.05658 0.07669662     3
25 2017-04-24      1 21.04452 0.07983165     3
26 2017-04-25      1 21.03691 0.07691438     3
27 2017-04-26      1 21.05846 0.07857017     3
28 2017-04-27      1 21.04128 0.07891908     3
29 2017-04-28      1 21.03837 0.07817021     3
30 2017-04-29      1 21.02334 0.07917546     3
36 2017-05-05      2 21.02890 0.07723042     4
37 2017-05-06      2 21.04606 0.07979641     4
38 2017-05-07      2 21.03822 0.07985775     4


# You can try removing a vector with the following
lapply(5:7, function(x) {
  dat <- CleanMachineData(test.data2, test.data2$switch, x)
  list(data = dat, means = aggregate(cbind(O2,CO2)~group, dat, mean))
})
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I needed. Thanks very much. I have one question though. Is it always the case that the first set of switch are not included in the code (i.e from 1 to 15 in this example)?

Comment: XD I was so focused on the switching that I didn't realize you want the values at the start before any switches happen. I'll manually put it in, give me a moment.

Comment: This is very nice indeed! Thanks again for the answer. So now if I choose another switch frequency (i.e. after 30 rows or so), I just need to replace the corresponding numbers in your code, right? :D 

Also, although this is already excellent, I just want to ask if there is a way to put the average values to the start (or end) of those remaining 5 rows> If not then that's okay (sorry I'm very new to R)!

Comment: So it's not exactly easily to call if it is only at the start or end of the usable data groups, can you explain how you want to use the averages? Or you just want them visually there?
Also, see edit on refined code, i made a function for you :D
Doesn't include the mean yet, still working

Comment: Oh what I want to use the averages is for further calculations (I won't bother you with the details but essentially I just need a way to call for those average values). That function that you wrote looks so complicated to me xD but it does what I want so I'm definitely going to use it. One final question about that function you just made, if I choose the switching frequency to be 30 instead of 10, and the unreliable rows are half of those, do I replace the "UnreliableRow=5" with "...=15"?

Comment: Only if your machine doesn't calibrate properly the first half of its observations :D. The "UnreliableRows" value is the number of rows at the start you will not include in your final data. Tried to make it easy for you to change. You should easily be able to call the mean by group as above. That's the benefit of adding that group column to the dataset ~

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139876/discussion-between-evan-friedland-and-tung-linh).

Comment: Yes, I understand it now. Thank you ever so much for your time and efforts in giving me the detailed answers :D

Comment: Final edits describing the function are up
Best of luck

Comment: Erased a bunch of unnecessary stuff in that function. Got a little weird.

Comment: I added a question in the chat. can you help me with it? :D

Comment: I'm in the chat~

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much Evan!

Comment: Made one more small edit to the function so you understand the if then statement more easily. No problem!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
test.data[rep(c(FALSE, TRUE), each=5),]
```

to select always the last five rows from the group of 10 rows.
Then you can use aggregate:

```
d2 <- test.data[rep(c(FALSE, TRUE), each=5),]
aggregate(cbind(O2, CO2) ~ 1, data=d2, FUN=mean)
```

If you want the average for every 5-rows-group:

```
aggregate(cbind(O2, CO2) ~ gl(k=5, n=nrow(d2)/5L), data=d2, FUN=mean)
```

Here is a generalization for the situation of arbitrary number of rows in `test.data`:

```
stay <- rep(c(FALSE, TRUE), each=5, length.out=nrow(test.data))
d2 <- test.data[stay,]
group <- gl(k=5, n=nrow(d2)/5L+1L, length=nrow(d2))
aggregate(cbind(O2, CO2) ~ group, data=d2, FUN=mean)
```

Here is a variant for mixing the data with the averages:

```
group <- gl(k=10, n=nrow(test.data)/10L+1L, length=nrow(test.data))

L <- split(test.data, group)
mySummary <- function(x) {
  if (nrow(x) <= 5) return(NULL)
  x <- x[-(1:5),]
  d.avg <- aggregate(cbind(O2, CO2) ~ 1, data=x, FUN=mean)
  rbind(x, cbind(date=NA, switch=-1, d.avg))
}
lapply(L, mySummary) # as list of dataframes

do.call(rbind, lapply(L, mySummary)) # as one dataframe
```

Comment: that's clever! Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: I tried this, and it worked fine until the "average" part. It shows the average of all the data left in the console. However, I want it to average each group of 5 rows after the deletion and put the new average values to new columns (either at the beginning or the end of the remaining 5 rows). How do I do that?

Comment: Thank you! It works, but any idea on how to add those 2 columns onto the data frame? Right now, it just prints the results to the console

Comment: is it going to mess up the data? Because I will need them for further calculations, so I thought that putting them in the data frame is easier to call for the values in the future. If it's not possible then probably I will need to call for those values otherwise somehow.

Comment: I see. Thank you!